# Simple Django Form with Bootstrap

Tags: css, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Django template that uses bootstrap:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label form="test2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">test2field</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter test2" id="{{ form.test2 }}">
</div>
```

I want to use each form field - e.g. `{{ form.testn }}` to display each field, rather than `{{ form.as_p }}` or something similar.

The above however displays the "> at the end of each field in the browser, so clearly something is wrong. If I remove the "> it works OK, and formats correctly, but this obviously isn't right.

Can someone show me how to do this properly? Sorry for such a newbie question - I just can't seem to find the right answer anywhere!

Thanks.

Comment: you dont insert the {{ form.field }} inside the input ID field. Django will generate the input field for you. Just do {{ form.field }}

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

When I use {{ form.field }} inside of the id= section all the CSS formatting is applied - i.e. placeholder text, font formatting from my stylesheet etc. 

When I use just {{ form.field }} there's no formatting. 

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can format your form field for Bootstrap:

**form:**

```
self.fields['address'] = forms.CharField(
                            required=True,
                            error_messages = {'required': 'Address is Required!'},
                            label='Address',
                            max_length=50,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                  'class': 'form-control input-lg',
                                  'id': 'address',
                                  'placeholder': 'Address',
                                  'required': 'required',
                                  'oninvalid': "this.setCustomValidity('Address is Required!')",
                                  'onchange': "this.setCustomValidity('')",
                                      }),
                            )
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    {{ form.address }}
</div>
```

Here you can see how the form is rendered: https://tableagent.com/reservation-system/

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help. If the answer is correct, you can mark it as the accepted answer. That will indicate other users that this code is working.